# Reorder large matrix or extract rows in specific order determined by column pair values

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a large matrix I need to process, let's call it `Z`.
`Z` has elements in this format, approximately 200.000 rows:

```
 2     3     6   723
 3     4     7    65
 3     4     8    20
 3     6     9    10
 4     5     9   127
 4     5    10   120
 4     5    11   291
 4     7    14   576
 5     7     8   365
 5     9    11   216
 6     9    12    40
.....
```

There are no row repetitions. 
The 4<sup>th</sup> column represents a type of ID.
The first 3 columns of each row are sorted in ascending order.
The rows are also in ascending order of the values in the 1st column.

If 2 rows have the same number in the 1st column, the 1st one is the row with the smallest value in the 2<sup>nd</sup> column. Same principle applies for 3<sup>rd</sup> column. This can be seen in these rows for example:

```
 4     5     9   127
 4     5    10   120
 4     5    11   291
 4     7    14   576
```

I need to obtain a matrix in the format below, I've added spaces between rows so you can easily see the pattern.

To sum up, I need to obtain a matrix where a row needs to be immediately followed by all other rows that have in columns 1 & 2 the same pair of values the row has in columns 2 & 3. If there are no similar rows with the one currently processed, it just needs to be added to the matrix and the next row to be processed in a similar matter.

Watch below, pair (3,6) in columns `2:3`, pair (3,6) in columns `1:2`. Same for pair (4,7). No matches for pair (4,8).

```
2     3     6   723
3     6     9    10

3     4     7    65
4     7    14   576

3     4     8    20

4     5     9   127
5     9    11   216

4     5    10   120
4     5    11   291
5     7     8   365
6     9    12    40
```

I have the following code which is very slow considering how large `Z` is.

In `T` I'm collecting row indexes of `Z`. I haven't let it run completely since it took more than 30 minutes and unfortunately it would be useless with such a run time.

In the end I had hoped I would be able to do something like: `answer = Z2(T,:)` to obtain my matrix with rows in the desired order.

I'm using `Z2`, a copy of `Z` to extract the final answer variable because I'm modifying `Z` inside the while loop with zeros for the rows I've already tested and for patterns already found, to hopefully not end up with duplicates in the final answer.

```
Z2 = Z;
T = zeros(size(Z,1),1);
i = 0;
count = 1;
while size(T(T~=0),1) ~= size(Z,1)
    i = i + 1;
    if(isequal(Z(i,:),[0 0 0 0]))
        continue;
    end
    p = find(ismember(Z(:,1:2),Z(i,2:3),'rows'));
    T(count) = i;
    if(~isempty(p))
        T(count + 1:count + size(p,1)) = p;
    end
    Z(i,:) = 0;
    Z(p,:) = 0;
    count = count + size(p,1) + 1;
 end
```

Comment: Do you need the new matrix to contain repetitions? I mean: if `[2 3 6 X; 3 6 9 Y]` is a pair, should `[3 6 9 Y; 6 9 12 Z]` be a pair as well, with the `[3 6 9 Y]` explicitly copied?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Arghh, too tired, I apologize. No 2nd match needed. Reverting back code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a possible speedup could be to make the folowing replacement:

```
%// p = find(ismember(Z(:,1:2),Z(i,2:3),'rows'));
p = find( all(bsxfun(@eq, Z(:,1:2), Z(i,2:3)),2) );
```

This works because  `ismember` is not built-in, so that your loop cannot be accelerated efficiently by MATLAB's JIT compiler.

I have a feeling more can be done, but first try this out. On my PC (MATLAB R2010b, Win 7, 64-bit) there's a speedup of about 10×, but better profile on your machine in your context to verify.

Comment: Brilliant! I'm very grateful! It took 338.6 seconds to compute, it's a perfectly acceptable time for my purposes, thank you so much!